# Wildcard characters how to match several words?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard, azure-synapse

```
   CASE      
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]EXT[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'EXT', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]EST[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'EST', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]XTN[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'XTN', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]XT[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'XT', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]EX[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'EX', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]X[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'X', ' EXT ')
      WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '%[0-9]E[0-9]%' 
         THEN REPLACE(PhoneNumber, 'E', ' EXT ')
```

I have a bunch of `WHEN` conditions in the `CASE` clause. Is it possible to put them together in only 1 `WHEN` condition? Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse only supports wildcard characters.

Comment: I thought I was using sql server. But in my previous post, someone told me it is not. It is Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Does it make sense？`SELECT @@Version
Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15669.0 Jul 14 2022 22:09:30 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `Translate()`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([PhoneNumber] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('(555) 555-1212 Ext 25')
,('(555) 555-1212 Est 25')
,('(555) 555-1212 Ext25')
,('(555) 555-1212 Ex 25')
,('(555) 555-1212 E25')
,('(555) 555-1212 X25')
,('(555) 555-1212 # 25')
 

Select PhoneNumber
      ,replace(replace(replace(replace(
                              translate(PhoneNumber,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#'
                                                   ,'###########################')
                              ,'#','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡','Ext ')
                              ,'  ', ' '
                              )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
PhoneNumber             (No column name)
(555) 555-1212 Ext 25   (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 Est 25   (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 Ext25    (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 Ex 25    (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 E25      (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 X25      (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
(555) 555-1212 # 25     (555) 555-1212 Ext 25
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. What does replace `'#','†‡'` do?

Comment: @user8314628 This is a little technique that reduce N repeating characters down to 1.   So ###########... would be come #.    Gordon Linoff demonstrated this some time ago.   It expands then  reduces then eliminates.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. How about the other way `‡†`? Is it a typo or what?

Comment: @user8314628 Not a typo. I pick odd character combinations   This may illustrate better https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2f06fbe3fca4185616fb9082b7aa6b4d

Comment: @user8314628 To be clear,  you can substitute and sting   it could be 1st replace  zzzYYY 2nd replace YYYzzz  and then 3rd replace zzzYYY  ( back to the origninal)